# How can I Serialize/De-serialize a Boolean Value from FasterXML\Jackson as an Int?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, fasterxml

I'm writing a JSON Client for a Server that returns *Boolean* values as "0" and "1".  When I try to run my JSON Client I currently get the following Exception:

```
HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Boolean from String value '0': only "true" or "false" recognized
```

So how can I setup **FasterXML\Jackson** to correctly parse something like:

```json
{
   "SomeServerType" : {
     "ID" : "12345",
     "ThisIsABoolean" : "0",
     "ThisIsABooleanToo" : "1"
   }
}
```

**Sample Pojo's:**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"someServerType"})
public class myPojo
{
   @JsonProperty("someServerType")
   SomeServerType someServerType;

   @JsonProperty("someServerType")
   public SomeServerType getSomeServerType() { return someServerType; }

   @JsonProperty("someServertype")
   public void setSomeServerType(SomeServerType type)
   { someServerType = type; }
}
```

---

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"someServerType"})
public class SomeServerType 
{
   @JsonProperty("ID")
   Integer ID;

   @JsonProperty("ThisIsABoolean")
   Boolean bool;

   @JsonProperty("ThisIsABooleanToo")
   Boolean boolToo;

   @JsonProperty("ID")
   public Integer getID() { return ID; }

   @JsonProperty("ID")
   public void setID(Integer id)
   { ID = id; }

   @JsonProperty("ThisIsABoolean")
   public Boolean getThisIsABoolean() { return bool; }

   @JsonProperty("ThisIsABoolean")
   public void setThisIsABoolean(Boolean b) { bool = b; }

   @JsonProperty("ThisIsABooleanToo")
   public Boolean getThisIsABooleanToo() { return boolToo; }

   @JsonProperty("ThisIsABooleanToo")
   public void setThisIsABooleanToo(Boolean b) { boolToo = b; }
}
```

**Rest Client Line**
*Note 1:* This is using Spring 3.2
*Note 2:* toJSONString() - is a helper method that uses Jackson to Serialize my Parameters Object
*Note 3:* The Exception happens on *Reading IN* the result object

```
DocInfoResponse result = restTemplate.getForObject(docInfoURI.toString()
                                  + "/?input={input}",
                                  DocInfoResponse.class,
                                  toJSONString(params));
```

Comment: Please add your client's relevant code.

Comment: You can define getters methods for those values which return something like `return "1".equals(stringRepresentation);`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As Paulo Pedroso's answer mentioned and referenced, you will need to roll your own custom `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`. Once created, you will need to add the `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotations to your property; specifying the class to use for each.

I have provided a small (hopefully straightforward) example below. Neither the serializer nor deserializer implementations are super robust but this should get you started.

```
public static class SimplePojo {

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonSerialize(using=NumericBooleanSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using=NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    Boolean bool;
}

public static class NumericBooleanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Boolean bool, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeString(bool ? "1" : "0");
    }   
}

public static class NumericBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return !"0".equals(parser.getText());
    }       
}

@Test
public void readAndWrite() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // read it
    SimplePojo sp = mapper.readValue("{\"bool\":\"0\"}", SimplePojo.class);
    assertThat(sp.bool, is(false));

    // write it
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    mapper.writeValue(writer, sp);
    assertThat(writer.toString(), is("{\"bool\":\"0\"}"));
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need the Deserializer: Jackson will automatically deserialize 0/1 to a Boolean POJO property, without any annotation. And in my event I didn't need the Serializer either, since the server I'm calling is accepting and converting true/false literals for this field. I'm awarding the bounty anyway.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer Thanks, I appreciate the award. :) To be clear, Jackson appears to automatically deserialize the property if it comes in as a **number** but not as a **string**.

Comment: God forbid the JSON being deserialized does not contain the field, or it does and the value is empty. Jackson will throw a wrapped NPE that looks like this:

Failed converting object com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of custom deserializer, you could also simply have a setter like:

```
public void setThisIsABoolean(String str) {
  if ("0".equals(str)) {
    bool = false;
  } else {
    bool = true;
  }
}
```

since your method can claim different type than what you use internally.

And if you have to support both `Boolean` and `String`, you can indicate value is an `Object`, and check what you might get.

It should even be possible to have different type for getter method (`Boolean`) and setter (`String` or `Object`).

Comment: Good for mutable objects. If our POJO is immutable, we cannot use this method.

Comment: @galcyurio Same idea works with `@JsonCreator` annotated constructor and factory methods too wor what that's worth (or, equivalent for Builder-approach).