# Map json data to expected values in Spring Data JPA with Jackson Annotation

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I have json data like below:

```
{
  "data":[
    {"val":"1"},
    {"val":"2"},
    {"val":"3"}
  ]
}
```

But I am expecting something like this

```
{
  "data":[
    {"val":"Red"},
    {"val":"Green"},
    {"val":"Blue"}
  ]
}


@Column(name = "colorname")
@JsonProperty("val")
String colorName;
```

Is there any Jackson annotation that maps these numbers to colorNames while converting to Pojos? Or what could be the better way to get the expected result?

Comment: For this purpose, you need to define your custom serializer. please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297506/how-can-i-serialiize-deserialize-a-boolean-value-from-fasterxml-jackson-as-an-in

Comment: use custom deserializer or customize setColorName() method

Answer (score 1):

You could create an Ordinal Enum just like next:

```
public enum Color {
    Green, 
    Blue,
    Red
    //and so on
}
```

Then you would need a custom deserializer, you just need to do something like the next (specifying `field name` to the key and `writeString` to the color value):

```
public class ColorSerializer extends StdSerializer<Color> {

    public ColorSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ColorSerializer(Class<Color> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public void serialize(Color value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName("val");
        gen.writeString(value.toString());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

You must specify to use this serializer to your enum using annotation `@JsonSerialize` above Color enum as next:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ColorSerializer.class)
public enum Color {
     //....
}
```

Finally, you must change your type`colorName` property to `Color` enum type instead of String and annotate as Enumarted Ordinal type (JPA)

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
Color color;
```

Comment: Thanks Pau for your comment. I needed a deserializer to get the value from the JSON. But it is now solved.