# Parse 't'/'f' as booleans during CSV mapping

Tags: java, android, csv, jackson, deserialization

Consider I have a CSV as such:

```
name,city,active
abc,bcde,t
xyz,ghj,f
```

If I wanted to map this to a model how would I convert the `'t'` or `'f'` to proper booleans. I am using `jackson-dataformat-csv` mapping to do this

```
CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader().withNullValue("");
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
csvMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(SNAKE_CASE);
csvMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
MappingIterator<Article> iterator = csvMapper.readerWithTypedSchemaFor(Object.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(fileFromResponse);
List<Object> data = iterator.readAll();
```

Currently the mapping fails with this error message:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Boolean` from String "t": only "true" or "false" recognized
```

Is there any way I can specify in the schema that 't' or 'f' should be taken as booleans. Or is there another way I can deserialize it?

Comment: You can read them as strings and then write a simple util method to return you it's boolean result.

Comment: The csv is too long to read in memory. It leads to an out of memory error. That is why I'm trying to map it directly from file to model.

Comment: Take a look:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297506/how-can-i-serialiize-deserialize-a-boolean-value-from-fasterxml-jackson-as-an-in

Comment: that works for json. will it work with a csv file?

Comment: @PM77-1 json deserializer worked. If you want add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register a custom JacksonModule with a mapper for Boolean type:

```
private val YNToBooleanDeserializer = object : JsonDeserializer<Boolean>() {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Boolean {
        return p.readValueAs(String::class.java) == "t"
    }
}
```

to register, use:

```
csvObjectMapper.registerModule(SimpleModule().addDeserializer(Boolean::class.java, YNToBooleanDeserializer))
```